# Is there a known, fast algorithm for counting all subsets that sum to below a certain number?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, counting

I recognize that the [subset sum problem is NP-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). I have a different, yet similar problem, which I'll call *subset below-sum*:

- Given a set of integers, $S$, and a target number, $n$, what is the number of subsets of $S$ that sum to **less than** $n$?

For example, if $S$ is $\{1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 15\}$, and $n$ is $20$, the [answer](http://pastebin.com/raw/87CApTMU) is $38$.

Is this an NP-Complete problem? If not, what is a fast algorithm to compute the answer?

Comment: There is no fast algorithm, unless P=NP.

Comment: A counting problem can *never* be in NP, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Subset below-sum appears to be NP-Hard. This is informal, but consider, if you can solve subset below-sum in polynomial time, you can solve subset sum in polynomial time.

- Given: does any subset of $S$ sum to exactly $n$?
- Let $A$ be $subset\_below\_sum(n)$ and $B$ be $subset\_below\_sum(n + 1)$. If $B - A \gt 0$, the answer is yes, otherwise, the answer is no.

Comment: This doesn't show that the problem is NP-hard. It only shows that it's not in P unless P=NP. It could  be #P-hard, though.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : ​ ​ ​ It also shows that it's NP-hard under [non-adaptive 2-query reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-table_reduction). ​ (Although your other sentences are correct.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

The similar problem #Subset-Sum, in which we want to count the number of subsets summing to some target, is #P-complete (this is implied by [this paper](ftp://ftp.cs.rochester.edu/pub/papers/theory/08.tr929.The_complexity_of_Power-Index_Comparison.pdf)). This hints that your problem, which is clearly in #P, might also be #P-complete.

Comment: Can you explain the correspondence?  For instance, suppose $n=18$, so your plan is to add 16 to the set.  Why does a subset summing to $17$ in the new set correspond to a subset summing to at most $17$ in the original set?  For instance, consider a subset summing to 15 in the original set; what does it correspond to in the new set?  I'm not seeing it at the moment...

Comment: Right, this only works when $n-2$ is of the form $2^m-1$. But this doesn't sound like an insurmountable hurdle.

Comment: You have what we're interested in backwards. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I don't think so.

Comment: To be a parsimonious reduction from #-Subset-Sum to the OP's problem, we would need solutions in the new set to correspond to solutions in the old set. ​ Solutions in the new set are those summing to less than n-1, and solutions in the original set are those summing to exactly n-1. ​ You have things the other way around. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Ok, now I see your point...